# I want a beautiful custom window for my first cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, custom-controls

I'm a graphic designer - turned web designer - turned web developer - who is currently trying to turn into a mac developer. I've nearly done programming my first app. Is a very, very simple application but I'm happy because I'm learning a lot of new stuff.

The problem is: I don't like how it looks.

As you may guess, design is a very big deal for me, and I think that an app like this, that is very simple, should at least look very good. I'd like to do something like this:  http://transmissionapps.com/ a custom window, with custom colors et all.

I Think that I've already went trough half of the internet looking for info, but I didn't found anything I could make sense of. Maybe you can point me in the right direction on how to:

1) Customize the look of my main window
2) Customize the appearance of a table view.
3) Just the same with buttons.

If you know of any sample code, that will be great, I'm becoming obsessed with looking at somebody else's code.

Thanks! (sorry for the long post and the bad english)

Comment: Doesn't it suck when you look in the wrong half of the internet? :) Wish I could help!

Comment: Just a word of caution: Doing something differently just for the sake of doing it differently often makes for an app that's interesting to look at but hard to use. UI conventions exist for a reason. Think very carefully about whether a non-standard UI element will actually make your app *more* user-friendly than a standard element you could use in the same place.

Comment: And that goes double for the Mac. Mac users as a demographic are huge sticklers for design and tend to be pretty harsh on apps that don't fit into the overall environment. Even Apple's own QuickTime Player was slammed in the Mac community for using a pointlessly weird background, an overly "clever" drawer and wheels instead of sliders.

Comment: Chuck: And it has never really recovered, since it's never switched back to the standard QuickTime controller (i.e., it's always had a non-standard UI).

Comment: I know :) I've been doing UI design for the web for some time and I know UI conventions are there to be followed. But I'm stubborn and prefer to ditch the customization idea because it's a bad idea rather than because I can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [Drawing a custom window on Mac OS X](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html)? Seems like that will get you a custom window to start.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Brandon Walkin's BWToolkit.

http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/

It has a bunch of nice looking UI elements for use in IB.  It also has source code so you can modify it for your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out Apple's sample application](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/index.html), it may be what your looking for.