# How is this Cocoa window architected?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I'm designing and building a Cocoa app (OX X, not a Cocoa Touch iOS app). I see other apps like Evernote, Chrome or Xcode have complicated, interesting top bars for their windows. How are these designed? Is it a custom window? If so, what is done to add the extra real estate?

A regular top bar looks like:

[image]

Evernote's top bar looks like

[image]

Comment: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1489837/102937

Comment: Thanks Robert. I wasn't even sure if a window was the right thing to pursue as opposed to other elements like a menu. I'll run through this and other custom window tutorials and give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are these designed?

They're almost certainly using [NSToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-BABIFCFJ), a Cocoa class that makes it easy to add a number of icons, buttons, search bars, etc. to the top of a window such that the items look like part of the window title bar. It's impossible to *know* what they're using just by looking at them, but NSToolbar is one way to get that effect.

Here's a good example straight from the linked documentation:

[image: Keynote toolbar]

Comment: Thanks. I dont need specifics, just a direction to run in!